# Using eclipse Kepler, my changes to Perspective.java don't seem to be getting picked up

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have just installed eclipse Kepler and have created a plug-in project using the RCP Mail Template, however any changes that I am making to the Perspective.java are not getting picked up.

I have altered the code in the NavigationView.java and I can see those changes reflected when I launch the application.

I have even deleted the Perspective.java and updated the ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor.java where instead of having `return Perspective.ID`, I changed this to `return "test"` and the application still managed to launch successfully.

Completely stumped here, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a 'Window > Reset Perspective' to get Eclipse to update the cached perspective settings from the Perspective factory class.

If your RCP does not have this option you will either have to clear the workspace (try the 'Clean' checkbox on the Run Configuration), or you can add a menu item to call `IWorkbenchPage.resetPerspective()`

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks for your reply, but how can the eclipse perspective have anything to do with the perspective in the rcp application I am developing? If I open tabs in my application, those tabs appear to remain open when I launch the application again. When I comment out the lines in the Perspective.java to not add the NavigationView, this also doesnt appear to have any affect

Comment: You have to do the reset in your RCP. Also try starting with -clean or clear the metadata completely.

Comment: Hi Greg, as it is the RCP Mail example I am working with, there is not that option in the menus. I tried the -clean there and got the following -**!MESSAGE The -clean (osgi.clean) option was not successful. Unable to clean the storage area: C:\Users\Kenny\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\NewTest.product\org.eclipse.osgi**

Comment: Here are the arguments when running the application - `-os ${target.os} -ws ${target.ws} -arch ${target.arch} -nl ${target.nl} -consoleLog -clean` I have now changed my workspace to something smaller C:\workspaceKepler but still seeing same issue

Comment: Arguments look OK. I have never seen that error message so I don't know what the issue might be.

Comment: I have switched to a new workspace and am no longer seeing that error when using the -clean command. But even when I try to debug the application, the debugger does not stop at my debug points in the Perspective.java though recognises my debig points in other java files for this project

Comment: It is only called once when the perspective is used the first time, after that cached info is used. I was not sure but it looks like -clean is not enough to clear this info. See my update to the answer

Comment: Great thanks!! Ticking the 'Clear' checkbox on the main window of the run configuration has worked. I tried to upvote but my reputation isnt good enough at the moment :-( Thanks for taking the time to help, much appreciated!